# Convert from nvarchar to DateTime with am pm?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

In my table I have `myDate` column of type  `nvarchar(50)`.

The result I need is to select this date/time: `07/11/2013 11:22:07`

And I need to get `07/11/2013 11:22:07 am` from it (add `am/pm` to the original date&time).

I tried everything but get only the original data without am/pm.

This is an example from my query :

```
select convert(dateTime,myDate,100) as Date from Info
```

or

```
select convert(dateTime,myDate,0) as Date from Info
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: **(1)** since you're storing your date as a string, you need to convert that to a `DATETIME` first: `CAST(myDate AS DATETIME)`, **(2)** then [pick one of the pre-existing styles for `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(myDate AS DATETIME), 100)` - if none of those styles exactly match your needs, you'll either have to use `FORMAT` (in SQL Server **2012** and newer), or do a lot of string hacks yourself

Comment: I know...but i got this data as a fact and must use it this way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try this !!`

```
declare @date datetime
set @date='07/11/2013 11:22:07'

SELECT cast(convert(varchar(20),substring(convert(nvarchar(20),@date, 9), 0, 21) 
+ ' ' + substring(convert(nvarchar(30), @date, 9), 25, 2),105) as datetime)
```

Comment: better! but it returend as jul 11 2013 and not 07/11/2013

Comment: ok it is good but better to change the first sentence: substring(convert(nvarchar(20),@date, 9), 0, 21)  to the original variable (in my case - myDate) - return the info from the table and your :
+ ' ' + substring(convert(nvarchar(30), @date, 9), 25, 2) to add the AM/PM

Answer (score 0):

You can get AM/PM data using following query

```
declare @date datetime
select @date= CAST('07/11/2013 11:22:07' AS datetime)
select RIGHT ( CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date,9),2)
```

Comment: sorry .the query works only if data type is datetime.i have edited the post checked it.pls chk now.

Answer (score 0):

Your field is a `NVARCHAR` field so just return it without any conversion. In your query you convert string representation into the `DATETIME` type and returns it. Your browser software which shows query results convert `DateTime` value into string representation to show it to you and conversion format depends on this software usually you can change it changing Windows Regional Settings.